# Why is there no call to repository's update method for this request (Entity Framework, automapper, repository pattern)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, automapper, repository-pattern

I am trying to understand the code in following screenshot. After map operation, the object is not written back to the repository. What is this concept called? How does `SaveChangesAsync` make call to the update method on the repository?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does SaveChangesAsync make call to the update method on the repository?

The DbContext *is* the repository, and it's tracking the oldCamp object.  When [SaveChagnes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechanges?view=efcore-3.1)() is called it will [detect changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.detectchanges?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ChangeTracking_ChangeTracker_DetectChanges) to any tracked entities and take the appropriate action (insert,update or delete).

Comment: I know that the map method can be used to return target type object from source type. But in this screenshot, the map is used to update the target with source?

Comment: That appears to be the case.

Comment: Please can you share with me reference link to understand the various uses of the the map function.

Comment: It's not part of EF.  Perhaps AutoMapper https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Answer (score 0):

[Under the hood](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechangesasync?view=efcore-3.1) `SaveChangesAsync()` will automatically call `DetectChanges()` to discover any changes to entity instances before saving to the underlying database. This can be disabled via `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`.

Comment: Is this an entity framework concept or a repository pattern concept?

Comment: @variable this is Entity Framework method. So it looks like this is Entity Framework concept.